# How to control the volume of an android device from a pc

Tags: remote-control, volume

I want to ask if there is a quick way to control my android devices volume from my pc. All solutions I find in Google are the otherway round. So does anybody has an idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are a [bunch of apps to remote-control your Android](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement), several of them also allowing you to adjust volume etc. Another possibility would be using something like IF (formerly [IFTTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT)) and setup a matching "recipe".

Answer (score 9):

I am proud to announce that I have just published an application on Google Play Store and Github to address this exact problem.

It is (and will remain) free, without ads, and open source.

It will let you control the sound volume of your Android device remotely, easily, from any device that has a web browser (this includes PC or iPhone per example) and is connected to the same local network (Wifi).

You can get it :

on Google Play Store : [Web Remote Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tanaka42.webremotevolumecontrol)

on GitHub : [tanaka42/androidapp-webremotevolumecontrol](https://github.com/tanaka42/androidapp-webremotevolumecontrol)

Some times ago, I did land on this stackexchange question when searching how to control volume remotely easily. I did try the Vysor+SliderWidget solution, it did work, but I was not happy with that. Moreover that solution did not include iPhone as the remote controller. So I have built this app for myself, but finally I have decided to make it public.

If it can be useful to even a single person, I will be very happy.

EDIT : my app now has more than 150 users located all around the world : I am very happy :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try a remote control app that would allow you to control anything on your android phone from your computer. If you are okay with this approach you can try app called [Vysor - Android control on PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.vysor&hl=en).

Comment: thank you for the tip. Vysor is great although I have trouble finding the volume control within vysor. I can only access them if my smartphone is locked. Do you know how to access the volume?

Comment: I am not sure about a specific one, but there are volume control widgets that can be placed on the screen once and can be easily accessed through remote.

Answer (score 1):

I found a free workaround: on your android device where you want the volume to be changed, install tasker and pushbullet. Also install pushbullet on your device that you want to use as your remote (this can also be a computer or ios device). Simple configure pushbullet on both devices so you can push notifications to each other. Then open tasker and make a new profile > event > filter on 'push' > 'receive a push' > configuration > filter on text: 1 > new task > media volume to 1. Repeat this for text: 2 > media volume: 2 etc. Send 2 and tasker will set your media volume to 2. If testing its good to know that sometimes tasker needs a restart before changes are made.
Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use an application called [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/download/)
for this. Install it to your pc (allow USB debugging from your mobile phone) and you can control your phone from it as long as it is connected to your pc or mac.

You get 1 ad every half an hour but it is the best app that I have found so far.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is: you'll need a desktop app that will communicate to your Android app via TCP/IP or Bluetooth (BluetoothAdapter) which will control the entire volume of the mobile.