# How to control the volume of an Android device from an iPhone?

Tags: applications, remote-control, ios, volume

How to control the volume of an Android device from an iPhone?

Comment: Something about the self-promotional question/answer pair seems a little "off", but we'll leave it to the community at large to decide.

Comment: I totally agree, I would totally understand if that question was deleted. I did not do that question/answer earlier because indeed, it is self-promotion. But the thing is : 1/ my app is (and will remain) free, no ad, open source, I earn nothing from it. 2/ I talked about my app in the linked question, but my app can be the answer to more questions (remote not only from PC) 3/ finally, that article made me think it was ok, "a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge" : https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @tanaka42 FWIW, free/no-ad/open-source is not a factor to decide if it's spam or not. SE has a guideline for [self-promotion](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in that it has to be non-excessive and always disclosed. The fact that you disclosed it here seems okay-ish, I think.

Comment: Understood. Thank you I will read the guideline carefully. I did edit my answer so the self-promotion disclosure is even more obvious. I have also added alternative solutions to my product so not all my answer is self-promotional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my *free open-source and no-ad* app, **Web Remote Volume Control**, I have made it myself to address this exact purpose, see my answer on [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228464/330150).
**Full disclosure: I am the author of this free, ad-free, and open-source app.**

You could instead use Teamviewer plus a slider widget ([Teamviewer Remote Control](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/teamviewer-remote-control/id692035811) on the iPhone, [Teamviewer Quick Support](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=fr&gl=US) on the Android device, and also a sound volume slider widget on the Android device), but this may not be free.

You could maybe also use [Airdroid](https://help.airdroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046722294-How-to-Remote-Control-Android-Device-from-an-iOS-Device-), but I think it is not free either.

Comment: Something about the self-promotional question/answer pair seems a little "off", but we'll leave it to the community at large to decide.

Comment: I added a full disclosure for the author.  I think between the OP's good-faith edits and the disclosure, this answer is good now.  I've upvoted it.